# Why would an ArcGIS 10 Python custom tool fail without throwing a "failed to execute" or "completed script" message at the end?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, tools

I have written a custom tool in Python for ArcGIS that converts in batch SHP files to GML files.  It processes one file at a time in a folder, file, or ZIP file and then moves on to the next.  If the tool experiences an exception it states that an error happened and just continues to the next file.

What one of the users of the tool experienced after kicking it off overnight is that it ended in a strange way.  Usually when the tool ends (prematurely or not) it has a message at the end saying "failure to execute " or "completed script ".  This time, however, it did not (as the image below shows).

[image: Image showing lack of confirmation of completion or error.]

Is there a specific reason why the script would just end abruptly like this, like maybe the process just quit for some reason? I asked the user if the computer restarted or if he noticed if ArcCatalog closed and he said no.

Comment: With out code no body is able to comment on this but if you are using Data Interoperability for this task just see the log files in windows User folders > Safe Software > Interoperability > logs. This will give you a better picture what is happening.

Comment: Is he sure the task ended? Maybe the task somehow got hung on the last file and the script was simply still executing.